# Есть фиксированное количество чисел(строк). Необходимо внести эти числа в двумерный массив и сосчитать их количество

Tags: c#

Есть массив, в котором определённое количество чисел n(задаётся извне, ранее уже известно). Необходимо занести уникальные числа в двумерный массив в один столбец и во втором сосчитать их количество.

Вот пример, один из случаев, массив `string[] arr` где n=2(2 числа):
5 12 12 12 5 12

И результат:

5 2

12 4

Лично у меня есть 2 варианта: использовать словарь `Dictionary<string, int>` или же двумерный массив `string[,]`. Пытаясь сделать задание, я лично придерживался второго варианта, так как он мне показался надёжнее, создав массив:

```
string[,] numArray = new string[n,2]
```

Где, очевидно, n - количество чисел и 2 - два столбца для уникальных чисел и их количества. Но по самому решению поставленной задачи(счёту чисел) туплю и не могу ничего придумать. Рассматриваю как дополненные предложенные, так и другие варианты. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `var result = arr.GroupBy(x=>x).Select(x=>new{ Value = x.Key, Count = x.Count });` (на коленке написан). Если прям массив, то уж думаю сами перегоните в нужное? Главное логика - группируем, потом формируем результат.

Comment: Выглядит неплохо, но слишком сжато. Я не указал этого в условии, но есть такие ключи, которые нужно пропустить(например, есть пустные строки вместо символов). Хоть и понимаю, что можно попытаться вычистить массив заранее, можно ли как-то это учитывать и в вашем запросе?

Comment: `есть такие ключи, которые нужно пропустить` -> перед группировкой `.Where(x=>x != ...)` (точки это естественно значение). А по поводу "сжато" - я бы сказал "просто" ) Вы сейчас городите себе кучу лишнего, всякие массивы, циклами будете обходить, когда задача решается одним LINQ запросом, и собственно зачем городить велосипеды, когда есть готовое решение?

Comment: Можно узнать, а как подобные выражения называются и есть ли книжечки\ресурсы (если вы таковые знаете), где о них можно поподробнее почитать? Уж больно лаконично они смотрятся.

Comment: Я отредактировал коммент выше, зовется LINQ

Comment: Быть может `Dictionary<int, int>`?

Comment: Предположим, словарь. В таком случае как посчитать количество ключей?

Comment: @Ilya дописал про это в ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
Dictionary<int, int> numbers = arr.Select(x => int.Parse(x))
                                  .GroupBy(x => x)
                                  .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count);
```

`Linq` решение выше, покажу еще обычное решение.

```cs
string[] arr = new string[] { "5", "12", "12", "12", "5", "12" };
Dictionary<int, int> numbers = new Dictionary<int, int>();
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
   int number = int.Parse(arr[i]);
   if (numbers.ContainsKey(number))
       numbers[number]++;
   else
       numbers[number] = 1;
}
foreach (var pair in numbers)
    Console.WriteLine($"{pair.Key} {pair.Value}");
```

Вывод в консоль

```
5 2
12 4
```

Если в исходном массиве есть не только числа, но и другой мусор, то тело цикла замените на это.

```cs
if (int.TryParse(arr[i], out int number))
{
   if (numbers.ContainsKey(number))
       numbers[number]++;
   else
       numbers[number] = 1;
}
```

Тогда все что не спарсилось в `int`, будет пропущено.

> В таком случае как посчитать количество ключей?

Чтобы вывести количество ключей массива, надо понимать, что количество ключей равно количеству значений и равно количеству элементов в словаре.

```cs
Console.WriteLine(numbers.Count);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь, это то, что мне нужно было, хотя по мере решения задачи могут ещё вопросы появиться, но это уже слабо касается вопроса.
Извиняюсь, что не отвечал, так как задача большая, и я отвлекался на пару дней на другие задачи, отдыхая от уже надоевшей.